# xcode/tesseract, use image from photo library

Tags: ios, xcode, tesseract, image-recognition, text-recognition

Im using tesseract for text recognition.
My problem is to get the photo from the photo library and then use tesseract.

My code:

```
import UIKit
import TesseractOCR

class ViewController: UIViewController, G8TesseractDelegate, 
UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var TextView: UITextView!
@IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self

    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

    image.allowsEditing = false


    self.present(image, animated: true){

    }


    if let tesseract = G8Tesseract(language: "dan+eng") {
        tesseract.delegate = self
        tesseract.image = UIImage(named: image)?.g8_blackAndWhite()
        tesseract.recognize()

        TextView.text = tesseract.recognizedText
    }
    func progressImageRecognition(for tesseract: G8Tesseract!) {
        print("Recognition Progress \(tesseract.progress) %")
    }

}
```

in the line:

```
tesseract.image = UIImage(named: image)?.g8_blackAndWhite()
```

it says:

> Cannot convert value of type UIImagePickerController

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare your `image` object as type `UIImagePickerController`:

```
let image = UIImagePickerController()
```

Yet, you're passing it as a string in `UIImage(named: image)?...`.

You need to put a string for the initializer `UIImage(named: String)` like `UIImage(named: "myImage.png")`.
If you want the user to be able to pick an image and then process it, you need to get the image picked from the `UIImagePickerController` and then process that one.
There are many tutorials on this topic available online, like [this one](http://www.codingexplorer.com/choosing-images-with-uiimagepickercontroller-in-swift/).